# Axiom of Regularity doesn't prevent Russell's Paradox?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I may just be misunderstanding something here, but according to ZFC a set can not be a member of itself or this could lead to Russell's paradox.

despite this, I seemed to have found a contradiction. I'm not saying that I think I'm right, but I would like someone to point out my misunderstanding.

the axiom of regularity is:

$(\exists A)(A\ne \emptyset \implies(\forall x)(x\in A\implies (\forall y)(y\in x\implies y\notin A))$

now if we define a set y to be

$y=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n,y\}$ where all $x_i$ are individuals and not sets.

the set should not exist so we try to find a contradiction.

the axiom of regularity implies

$(\exists x)(x\in y\implies x\cap y=\emptyset)$

so if we have that $x\in y$ then that must mean

$x=x_1\lor x_2\lor x_3\lor ...\lor x_n\lor y$

now if we have x=y we have our contradiction as $x\cap y=y\cap y=y$

but if instead, we have for any $x_i$, $x=x_i$ then no contradiction arises as the intersection of a set and a member is the empty set. or in the case, we say that this is not a well-defined concept than, at least in the book I am reading (Patrick Suppes Axiomatic Set Theory), an impossible set is defined to be the empty set.

Could someone explain the problem in my argument?

Comment: I don't think your definition of AR is right.

Comment: If it's about the $(\forall y)(y\in x\implies y\notin A)$ part, then I know this isn't exactly how it is typically written, but in the book the author says this form is equivalent and was only used to make it clear that the variable x was being used as a set variable.

Comment: The Axiom of Regularity is a universal statement: it says that for *every* set $A$ there is a set $x$ such that $x\in A$ and $x\cap A$ is empty. Your version of regularity says that there *exists* such a set... and that’s a theorem of ZFC: the set $\{\varnothing\}$ has the desired property. You’ve also got the quantification inside wrong: it’s not that *every* element of the set has the property, but that every set has an element with the property. You’ve got regularity entirely wrong as written.

Comment: The error is precisely that your version of Regularity is for a single set, not every set. If your $y$ were a set, then by Separation so would the set $z=\{x\in y\mid x=y\}$. That set is none other than $\{y\}$. But now the set $z=\{y\}$ does not satisfy regularity: because $y\in y$, so $y\cap z=\{y\}\neq\varnothing$. Thus, it’s not that your set itself contradicts regularity, but that your set allows the construction of another set that *does*.

Comment: P.S. Please try to make the titles informative; your title now gives absolutely no clue about what the question is about. That may prevent knowledgeable people from looking at it, and make it difficult for future users to locate if if they have a similar question.

Comment: The axiom of regularity has absolutely nothing to do with Russell's paradox.  Russell's paradox still works even if sets are not allowed to be elements of themselves.

Comment: @EricWofsey And conversely, there are set theories were sets *are* allowed to be elements of themselves, but in which Russell’s paradox does not manifest. (In a theory where sets are not allowed to be element’s of themselves, Russell’s construction yields the set of all sets... which *would* be an element of itself...)

Comment: The axiom of regularity is only to make some theory smoother: it allows us to define an ordinal as a set well-ordered by $\in$, and to get a nice hierarchy of sets based on rank, which makes some ZFC model theory easier. See Kunen's book e.g. It's a recent addition and has nothing to do with the paradox by Russell.. It's a safe axiom to assume, as we lose nothing of signifance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $y$ were a set, then by the Axiom of Separation you have that
$$ z= \{x\in y\mid x=y\} = \{y\}$$
is also a set.

But now $z$ does not satisfy the Axiom of Regularity: the only element of $z$ is $y$, but $y\cap z = \{y\}$, because $y\in y$ and $y\in z$. So $z$ does not have any element that is disjoint from $z$.

So while $y$ does not contradict Regularity directly, if $y$ were a set it would allow the construction of a set that *does*. That contradiction arises from the assumption that $y$ is a set, so we conclude that $y$ is not a set.

---

By the way, you’ve got the quantifications for Regularity wrong. It should be
$$\forall A(A\neq\varnothing\implies (\exists x(x\in A\wedge \forall y(y\in x\implies y\notin A)))).$$

---

**Added.**

Finally: the Axiom of Regularity is not what prevents Russell’s Paradox! In fact, there are set theories that *specifically* deny the Axiom of Regularity, and are as fine as ZFC is. Look up Aczel’s Anti-Regularity Axiom or “Quine atom”.

What allows for Russell’s Paradox is *unbounded comprehension*: that is, arbitrary set formation. That given any property $\varphi$, the collection of all $x$ with $\varphi(x)$ true is to be a set. Setting $\varphi(x)$ to be “$x\notin x$” is what yields Russell’s Paradox. But ZFC does not allow unbounded comprehension, it only allows separation. Other theories, such as Bernays-Goedel-von Neumann, allow arbitrary *class* formation, but not arbitrary *set* formation. The collection of all sets that are not elements of themselves turns out not be a set, but only a proper class, so it does not lead to a contradiction.

Comment: So my argument was right (barring the mistake in the axiom) in that the existence of the set isn't directly a contradiction, but it implies by the axiom schema of separation that a set can be constructed such that there would be a contradiction?

Comment: @JacobHulse: Well, if your argument was “this set, by itself, does not seem to contradict regularity”, then you are correct: it need not; but from that set you get one that does. On the other hand, there are consequences of regularity (“no set is an element of itself”, “there does not exist an infinite sequence of sets $x_1,\ldots,x_n,\ldots$ such that $x_{n+1}\in x_n$”) that **would** be directly contradicted by your set.  By the way: I’ve added a paragraph given your new title: no, regularity is actually not related to Russell’s paradox at all!

Comment: Thanks, I guess it has been a while since I read about Russell's paradox. I just had the vague reminiscence that it involved something to do with letting a set be a member of itself. I've been reading Patrick Suppes's Axiomatic set theory, do you have any book recommendations for reading on Russell's paradox?

Comment: @JacobHulse: Not specifically. But it’s easy to check that the Axiom of Separation already implies that there can be no set of all sets (given a set $A$, there always exists a set $B$ that is not an element of $A$: take $B=\{x\in A\mid x\notin x\}$ and verify that $B\notin A$). That suffices to avoid Russell’s Paradox (as well as other paradoxes such as Cantor’s Paradox) from manifesting. Regularity really doesn’t come into play for that, as the existence of non-well-founded set theories shows.